# Can I print to USB printer from Java on a Raspberry PI?

Tags: java, printing, raspberry-pi2

I am looking at creating a simple time clock. It will read barcoded id badges from an HID USB scanner. Most of it is simple to implement. Where I am stuck is when I consider writing the application in C# .net and using an old PC, or writing it for the Raspberry PI in Java. (I do not have any Java experience, but I am taking a semester class next month.)

I would prefer the Raspberry PI as the host for a number of reasons. The sticking point is, where on a Windows PC using .net there are printing facilities, I have had very little luck searching out the method where I could print the time sheets to a USB printer from the Raspberry PI using Java. (CUPS would be installed on a Raspbien OS.)

Now my question to the learned masses ...
Have you successful printed from a Java application to a USB printer connected to a Raspberry PI?  Do I study and use the same code on the Raspberry PI as I would use to print from Java on my Windows desktop, or does it need some other magic?

Comment: Assumed that you have a standard JDK installed on the PI, did you check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/?

Comment: Yes I did.  I wasn't sure if that would work on the PI.  The JRE and JDK on the PI are version 8, but I wasn't sure if all the functions, such as the standard java.awt.print and javax.print were full implemented on the PI. If they are, I am in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

I have found through other sources that with CUPS properly installed, printing from Java is fully functional using the same methods as on a Windows platform;  java.awt.print and javax.print.

That means I can use the Raspberry Pi for my barcode time clock project as soon as I learn enough Java.

KK

Comment: Unfortunately, after writing test applications that print fine on Mac, and Windows platforms, on the Raspberry Pi, it says it cannot find the print service.  That is with CUPS installed and the Pi properly printing through other programs. If anyone actually gets it working please post your success.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the JRE won't find the printer on a raspberry pi. Go to terminal on your raspberry pi with the printer connected and type `lpstat -a` and copy the printer's name that you are looking for. Then use this in your program:

```
String destination = "Your printer's name";
String path = "Your path to pdf";
String[] command = { "lp", "-d", destination, path};
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
```

The path to the pdf is relative to your current directory.

This program executes a command on your linux system to print your desired pdf through ProcessBuilder. It will only run on a linux system (raspberry pi).